# Overriding the classloader to get every loaded class bytes and name

Tags: java, runtime, classloader, reverse-engineering

Yes , so what im trying to do is getting the class bytes of every loaded class loaded by the jvm during run time . Instrumentation wont work for this case because the program im trying to load has encrypted his classes files and load it with its own class loader.

Here's my attempt : https://gist.github.com/MalikDz/944cae9c168fa05fbd0a

here the output (error) : https://gist.github.com/MalikDz/fdf20df16b951d41cb78

Thanks a lot !

Comment: anyone have an idea ?

Comment: If the `ClassLoader` refuses to work when an agent has been specified on the command line, simply attach the agent at a later time. `ClassLoader`s are not asked whether they like `Instrumentation` or not, thus they can’t prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Java Agent to do this trick:

The Agent is very straightforward: It registers a class transformer, which can get access to the byte-code:

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;

public class ClassDumpAgent
{
    /**
     * This method is called before the application’s main-method is called, when
     * this agent is specified to the Java VM.
     **/
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst)
    {
        ClassFileTransformer trans = new ClassDumpTransformer();
        inst.addTransformer(trans);
    }
}
```

The ClassFileTransformer that is used simply dumps the byte-array with byte-code to the file system:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class ClassDumpTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer
{
    private File rootFolder = new File("C:\\temp\\dump");

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, 
                            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer)
            throws IllegalClassFormatException
    {
        File dumpFile = new File(rootFolder,className+".class");
        dumpFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dumpFile);
            try {
                out.write(classfileBuffer);
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalClassFormatException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return classfileBuffer;
    }
}
```

To package this class dumping agent, you need to JAR the two classes and include a MANIFEST.MF for this agent:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
PreMain-Class: ClassDumpAgent
```

To run the application with this agent, use a command-line like this:

```
java -javaagent:cldumpagent.jar MyApplication
```

Some remarks about the solution:

1. The classes are dumped in a hardcoded folder (C:\TEMP\DUMP), you
   might want to change this.
2. The transformer will dump *all* classes, including the JDK Runtime. You might want to filter which packages are dumped.
3. Be careful with reverse-engineering, in some countries this might be considered illegal.

Barry

Comment: not trying to be rude but I stated above that instrumentation doesnt work here . Also I already do this : https://gist.github.com/MalikDz/18e410aa4e30a3379603.   But thanks for trying tho <3

Comment: Have you tried to decompile the ClassLoader that is performing the decryption? Perhaps you can decompile the class, add a method to dump the plaintext bytecode ?

Comment: When you say 'doesnt work here', do you mean that you can't use agents, or the ClassFileTransformer still receives the encrypted bytes?

Comment: Are you trying to dump the classes on Windows? This will probably fail since Windows cannot handle certain filenames, such as CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, etc. Some obfuscators create classes in packages like 'auX', which Windows cannot save. Either run on Unix, or add some escape logic in the ClassDumpTransformer...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your classes are protected by Allatori obfuscator. During the Boot process it checks if there is an '-javaagent:' command-line argument, if present it simply stops.
To workaround this, you can decompile the Boot class, find the (encrypted) string for '-javaagent:', and replace that string in the .class file with some random chars. Also remove the 'Sealed: true' in the MANIFEST, so that you can start with modified classes. Finally you should be able to start with 'java -javaagent:cldumpagent.jar -jar modified.jar -restarted'